# Не могу изменить txt файл с помощью pyinstaller

Tags: python, pygame, pyinstaller

Не могу сохранить лучший рекорд в игре используя `pyinstaller`.

Использую такую функцию для записи:

```
def resource_path(relative):
    if hasattr(sys, "_MEIPASS"):
        return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative)
    return os.path.join(relative)

pathbestscore = resource_path(os.path.join('maps', 'bestscore.txt'))

sc += 1 if sc // 5 > bsc:
    bsc = sc // 5
    newbest = True

if newbest:
    with open(pathbestscore, "w") as file:
        file.write(str(bsc))
```

Comment: _`sc += 1 if sc // 5 > bsc:`_ - это что за дичь?

Comment: Вроде как файлы, которые указываются в ресурсах PyInstaller временные и удаляются после закрытия программы. Добавляйте файл в папке выполнения программы, а не в в `_MEIPASS`.